# keyvalue pair in jquery autocomplete

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-autocomplete

Hi In my android phonegap app,i have used jquery autocomplete feature.I need to get the keyvalue pair in autocomplete

Here is my example code:

```
var Person = [{"Prateek":"hello"},{"James":"android"}];

$(".searchbox").autocomplete(Person);
```

When i type 'j' in the textbox i need to get android instead of james in the autocomplete textbox.But i am getting error and result is not shown in textbox.And i am using autocomplete js which can be used also in asp.net

Please guide me where i am wrong.Thanks In Advance

Comment: Which implementation are you using? There are several of them that uses that same name.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the following links, the ordering does matter

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

then use autocomplete like this

```
$(".searchbox").autocomplete(source: Person)
```

jquery ui can be download here http://jqueryui.com/download/

EDIT:
you can also look at listviews at jquery mobile [docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/#&ui-state=dialog)

Comment: This also not working i and i am not using jquery ui..Please guide me

Comment: without using jquery ui i need to get the result.

Comment: you need to have jquery ui or download some other plugin

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/#&ui-state=dialog

Comment: Thanks Clinton..I am using ashx for getting autocomplete results.It was working fine,but not working when in use jquery ui.Please guide me.